# What is the techical reason the JavaScript regex class \w cannot be changed?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

There was a [proposal](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/es-regexp-unicode-character-class-escapes) to update certain regex character classes like `\w`, `\d`, `\b`, etc. when used with the unicode regex flag `u` (relevant ES-discuss [thread](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/questions-regarding-es6-unicode-regular-expressions#content-5)).

Reading that thread, some very good arguments are presented why `\d` should not be messed with, the most import of which is that JavaScript can't cast or coerce non-ASCII digit characters to numbers. But as far as I can tell, the same logic doesn't really apply to `\w`.

Is there a compelling *technical* reason or edge-case I'm not seeing here?
 After all we're talking about an opt-in flag.

Part of the reason I ask is that in every other language I'm familiar with its possible to write a simple regex that matches any unicode word character whereas in JavaScript one must essentially specify code point ranges.

Comment: Isn't backward compatibility a technical reason? See AFB's note [here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/questions-regarding-es6-unicode-regular-expressions#content-12) in particular: *"Except, as discussed WRT \d, if a JS programmer updates an existing regexp using /u simply because they want to allow for "full Unicodee" they may not also realize that they are changing matching semantics changes in other ways. As Claude said, this will cause bugs."* One can agree or disagree with AFB about this, but I'm not clear what you're looking for beyond that.

Comment: unicode also covers the special characters like `&` which user would not want to match.

Comment: @gurvinder372 `\w` does not match `&` in any language I'm familiar with. It only matches *word* characters and underscores (which has nothing to do with unicode).

Comment: @JaredSmith it doesn't match `&` right now since it is special character. But if `\w` is enhanced to match unicode as well then it will match `&` as well, right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess I'm not sure how that changes the matching semantics noticeably for `\w` ...other than it would make it work as expected for someone coming from other languages. How would that break existing code?

Comment: @gurvinder372 no. Again, `\w` matches *word* characters. python https://regex101.com/r/P9Tpry/1 and pcre https://regex101.com/r/P9Tpry/2 examples.

Comment: @JaredSmith I know that it currently matches `word` characters that fall under `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`. **Point is** - If it is enhanced to match **unicode** characters as well, then it will match some special characters also.

Comment: @gurvinder372 did you even look at the examples I linked? Do you know what a *word* character is? `\w` doesn't match punctuation, except the underscore, in *any* language, unicode flag or no.

Comment: The u modifier is problematic in other languages because it makes two different things (reading the string as a unicode string and modifying the character classes) and it isn't always possible to choose which behaviour you want (it's possible with pcre in a certain extent). I think a good compromise is to have two modifiers (one that changes the character class meaning and one that informs the regex engine that it must read the string as a unicode string and not byte by byte); and why not a third for the two behaviours at the same time.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks! That's exactly the kind of consideration I was wondering about. If you put that as an answer I will upvote and pending any other hats in the ring accept.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Thanks but it is more a consideration and a wish than a technical reason.

Comment: You can also read about the `u a l d` modifiers in Perl here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers